# 'd' Key on VNC Viewer Minimises All Windows

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, vnc

I'm running vnc4server on an Ubuntu 10.10 box, and connecting to it from an Ubuntu 8.04 machine using TightVNC Viewer 1.3.9. I'm unable to type anything with the character <kbd>d</kbd> within the VNC session, as the <kbd>d</kbd> causes all windows to be minimised.

Following reports of a successful solution on many online fora, I disabled the keyboard shortcut for hiding all windows, but the problem persists.

Output of `xev` is given below. It includes two presses of <kbd>d</kbd> because the first press minimised all windows. I didn't know what to keep and what to remove, so this output includes everything from the first key-press to when the windows came back up on the second key-press:

```
FocusOut event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor               

FocusOut event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear      

FocusIn event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyPointer       

KeymapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

LeaveNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x2e, subw 0x0, time 581275388, (100,64), root:(111,572),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,    
    focus YES, state 0                                            

UnmapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    event 0xa00001, window 0xa00001, from_configure NO      

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    atom 0xc7 (WM_STATE), time 581275388, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    atom 0xae (_NET_WM_STATE), time 581275388, state PropertyNewValue

MapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    event 0xa00001, window 0xa00001, override NO          

VisibilityNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured                                   

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    (0,0), width 178, height 10, count 3               

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    (0,10), width 10, height 58, count 2               

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    (68,10), width 110, height 58, count 1             

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    (0,68), width 178, height 110, count 0             

EnterNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x2e, subw 0x0, time 581276874, (100,64), root:(111,572),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967283 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    atom 0xc7 (WM_STATE), time 581276874, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    atom 0xae (_NET_WM_STATE), time 581276874, state PropertyNewValue

FocusIn event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  68  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

FocusOut event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967214 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal inside the VNC session. Press `d` in the xev window. Copy-paste the output (if any) into your question.

Comment: Given the `xev` output, the `d` key is caught by your window manager. What window manager or desktop environment are you running? Try launching a minimal or no window manager (just an `xterm`) in the VNC server: create `~/.vnc/xstartup` containing just `xterm&`, and try `xev` there.

Comment: In my case, Cairo-dock's logout icon had registered 'Super-L' as a short-cut to logout with the same 'Grab/Ungrab' results in xev. Removing that shortcut (which I never use anyway) resolved the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I had made the silly assumption that the key bindings were global when in fact, they are per-user. I had changed the key bindings logged in as root, but was logging into a VNC session created by another user. The 'hide all normal windows…' shortcut was set to <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for this user. The standard solution—changing it to something else, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>—fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use openbox as window manager instead of metacity for VNC sessions.
Metacity shortcuts will not work, and <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does not break anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I have seen the same question asked on 5 different stackexchange sites, and all the answers say to just remove the hotkey, which does work, but isn't the root of the problem (at least it wasn't for me). The real problem is that the windows super key is not mapped correctly, as is described here:

[i3 ignores mod4 (windows key) when in VNC session](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/5383/i3-ignores-mod4-windows-key-when-in-vnc-session/?answer=5384#post-id-5384)

Basically just run these two commands

```
xmodmap -e "clear mod4"
xmodmap -e "add Mod4 = Super_L"
```

That should do it. Now the desktop should only be shown if you hold down the super (windows) key as well. The "d" key (and other keys with super shortcuts) should now work as expected.

You may need to replace Super_L with something else depending on your keyboard, check the link above for details.